# Write an entire PowerShell property value to the console

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

`Select-Object` is currently truncating the result as follows.

```
> Invoke-WebRequest "http://www.wikipedia.org" | select content

Content
-------
<!DOCTYPE html>...
```

How do we write the entire result to the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select command is wrapping your result in a powershell object with a single "content" property. Just tell it to return the expanded result:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://www.wikipedia.org" | select -ExpandProperty content
```